# Python Ignoring few x number of lines in CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I'm trying to read from a CSV file that's tab-delimited saved as a .DAT file.
I need to skip everything until I get to the data portion under the Date header.

So 05-29-2012 and everything on that row and rows below it. I found plenty of documentation on how to skip the first few lines, but I don't know how many lines that may be. From the
"Data file created", to the meat of the data may have more lines of text than another file. Could
be 3 rows, could be 10 rows.

I have thousands of these files I'm trying to extract the data out of and plot it. Easy in excel just to cut and paste but I'm going for efficiency here.

This is the code I'm using. I see that data perfectly. Only IF I know how many lines to skip. There will be blanks lines, I get how to bypass those, but if I have text there, that adds the extra lines I can't bypass.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

myfile = ('E:\\TTF Data Backup\\1X ARRAY MOD #2.dat')
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, skiprows=3 , delimiter='\t')
print(df.head(20))
```

[Data File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHreO.jpg)

Comment: Does every file have the same column names?  And how is the data delimited?

Comment: Yes, every file has the exact same columns below the headers. Just whats above the headers may change. It is tab delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
myfile = ('E:\TTF Data Backup\1X ARRAY MOD #2.dat')

skipcnt = 0
with open(myfile) as f:  # auto closes after loop
   for row in f:
       skipcnt += 1
       if "Tension" in row and "Elong" in row:  # top of header
            break;
skipcnt += 3  # skip headers

df = pd.read_csv(myfile, skiprows=skipcnt , delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Ah ha! You sir are a genius. Works perfectly. I wondered if the actual headers could be played into this for a search option but couldn't wrap my small brain around it. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.